# How to know the rgb colour code for a certain named color in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rgb

In a ggplot2 plot, I want to use the function:

```
scale_fill_manual(
values = c(
'mediumorchid2',
'gold1',
'red'
)
```

I know the RGB code colour for 'red': #FF0000

The colors 'mediumorchid2' or 'gold1' also have this kind of code. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're talking about the hex representation, not the RGB. The RGB representation is three numbers (either between 0 and 1 or 0 and 255) giving the red, green, and blue levels.

To get the RGB representation, you can just use the base function `col2rgb()`:

```
col2rgb('mediumorchid2')
#       [,1]
# red    209
# green   95
# blue   238
```

I have long had a personal convenience function for getting the hex representation, as it's a task I need to do often:

```
col2hex <- function(x, alpha = "ff") {
    RGB <- col2rgb(x)
    return(apply(RGB, 2, function(C) {
        paste(c("#", sprintf("%02x", C), alpha), collapse = "")
    }))
}
col2hex('mediumorchid2')
# [1] "#d15feeff"
```

### Update:

[Gordon Shumway's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61741024/8386140) mentions that apparently there is a package with such a function already! I would recommend that. However, I leave my answer up both for the discussion of RGB vs. hex and in case you don't want a dependency on `gplot`.

Answer (score 3):

The gplots package has a function named `col2hex()`:

```
library(gplots)
col2hex("gold1")
"#FFD700"
```

Comment: That's cool! Didn't know it was already available in a package. I had to make my own code for it years ago and didn't notice that development